# Replace a string from a set of string in a file - SED

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, sed

I am having a trouble replacing string coming from a set of string from a File
So here's how I would like my script to run

I have these files: 
macadd.file

```
00:90:8F:56:63:88
00:90:8F:56:63:77
00:90:8F:56:63:6B
00:90:8F:56:63:86
00:90:8F:56:63:87
00:90:8F:56:64:E5
```

test.file

```
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
```

So I've tried replacing it using

```
for i in $(cat macadd); do sed -i "s/00:90:8F:56:63:88/$i/g" test;done
```

However, it only changes it from the first string in macadd.file
You can see that 00:90:8F:56:63:88 is all the entry there. What I would like to happen is like this, the result:

```
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:77; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:6B; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:86; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:87; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:64:E5; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
```

Comment: Tangentially, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 1):

Actually for the example you present in the question something without the substitution would be more simple and clear:

```
<macadd.file xargs -I{} printf "host Accountant { hardware ethernet %s; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }\n" {}
```

That is for every line in the input file call printf to substitute only the MAC address part. More trouble comes when you have more MAC addresses and more resulting IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The first pass across causes `sed` to replace all the hits with the first value.  If that's not what you want, use a different `sed` script.  Perhaps like this:

```
sed 's!.*!s/00:90:8F:56:63:88/&/;n;!' macadd.file
```

This produces on standard output a new `sed` script, which you can pass to (... pause ...) `sed`.

```
sed 's!.*!s/00:90:8F:56:63:88/&/;n;' macadd.file |
sed -f - -i test.file
```

This is a slightly demanding pattern the first time you see it (and `sed -f -` does not work on all platforms) but once you get the idea, having a script generate a script is a very powerful and versatile tool for your toolbox.

... On MacOS, you can't use `sed -f -` and also `-i` requires an argument. If you have Bash (or some other shell which supports process substitution), here's a workaround:

```
sed -f <(sed 's!.*!s/00:90:8F:56:63:88/&/;n;!' macadd.file) -i '' test.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Straightforwardly with **`AWK`**:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[NR]=$1; next }
     a[FNR]{ sub("00:90:8F:56:63:88", a[FNR]) }1' macadd tesfile > tmp_f && mv tmp_f testfile
```

- `NR` - the total number of input records read so far
- `FNR` - the number of records that have been read so far from the current input file

The final `testfile` contents:

```
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:88; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:77; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:6B; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:86; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:63:87; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
host Accountant { hardware ethernet 00:90:8F:56:64:E5; fixed-address 192.168.10.29; }
```

Comment: The OP is unclear on whether the number of MAC addresses is lower than the number of lines in the test file.  I have assumed that they should be replaced in a rotating fashion; this script just runs out of MAC addresses, and replaces them with an empty string if the target file is longer. (Easy to fix; just add a modulo calculation to the index subscript.)

Comment: @tripleee, if the target file is "longer", then no replacement will be made, it's obvious

Comment: I thought it *obvious* that that would be undesirable, but anyway, it's easy to select one behavior or the other with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If MAC adresses are not always the same in test.file
You can try :

```
sed -E '
s/((([[:xdigit:]]){2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2})(.*)((([[:xdigit:]]){2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2})(.*)/\4\1\8/
# ((([[:xdigit:]]){2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}) catch the MAC addresse
s/^\t//
# remove tab which come from paste
/^((([[:xdigit:]]){2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2})/d
# remove lines if maccad.file have more lines than test.file
'<<< $(paste macadd.file test.file)>test.file
```